# cmake, how to automate windows SDK build?

Tags: winapi, cmake

I would like to automate the build of a project using cmake on Windows using the windows SDK compiler. I am developing on linux, and cannot cross-compile (I am building a library which will be linked to Matlab mex file, although I don't think this detail is that important).

I can successfully generate, nmake files, or visual studio solution files using cmake generators as desired, but how can I then build the project without user interaction?

It seems from reading around that you have to launch a special command prompt to set environment variables etc before building, is this the case and/or is there a workaround?

What are the steps for building a cmake project, starting from only CMakeLists.txt on windows, using the windows SDK, without any user interaction?

Note also that answers suggesting using a flavour of mingw are not what I'm looking for, I already know how to do it this way. I want the Windows SDK steps, or the steps for the express versions of the MSVC++ compilers are also of interest.

Comment: The "special" command-prompts just run a batch file to set the environment variables.  You can write a batch file that does this and then calls `nmake` or `cmake` or `msbuild` or whatever.  Unfortunately, the name and location of the batch file varies depending on the version and whether you've got the SDK or Visual Studio.  But this isn't a problem if you're targetting a particular build machine.

Comment: @arx, Yes, I understand from researching roughly what the batch commands do (i.e. set various environment variables). What I would like to know is if there's any way to achieve the same with minimal user interaction, to tell the build system where the batch file is or similar. I want to target a particular platform (e.g. Win 7 64Bit) rather than one particular build machine. If it helps you can assume I know the location of cl.exe whether it's on the path or not (Matlab will know this).

Comment: You've got this backwards. There is no such thing as *"the location of cl.exe"* - on any given system there can be any non-negative number of compilers installed. Setting up the environment variables will tell the build system, which one to use. Which environment to use for a particular build is decided by the developer, who then invokes the appropriate batch file. It is not something you can automate.

Comment: @IInspectable, ok, to clarify, I am really creating a library which will be linked into a Matlab mex file (this is really a shared library linked to some other Matlab libraries, a bit like a swig python wrapper). I am therefore requiring Matlab to have been set up to use a given compatible mex compiler, which on Windows is currently the Windows SDK 7.1. This is all I want my user to have to do. Once set up, Matlab then knows the location of this compiler, and I can extract this information in advance of running my automated cmake build.